# Fitting power-law distributions with poweRlaw package in R

Tags: r, power-law

With poweRlaw library, and once computed `alpha` and `xmin` with `estimate_xmin`, which formula the script uses to compute the fitted values?
I mean, assuming that y=C·x^(-alpha), my question is how the script computes the *normalization constant* from `alpha` and `xmin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normalising constant is fairly easy to calculate. See the [*Clauset et al's*](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062) powerlaw paper (in particular table 2.1). For the continuous case, *C = (alpha-1) xmin^(alpha-1)*, the discrete case involves calculating the diagamma function.

You can also examine the R code:

- [Discrete](https://github.com/csgillespie/poweRlaw/blob/master/pkg/R/pldis.R)
- [Continuous](https://github.com/csgillespie/poweRlaw/blob/master/pkg/R/plcon.R)

Comment: Thank you very much for your concise answer.